# ADB shell command not working from application

Tags: android, shell, xposed-framework

I am creating an Android App (Xposed module) that disables applications (packages). When I run the command from `adb shell` it runs perfectly. But from my application I am not able to figure out why it is not working.

Here is the code:

```
try {
    Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(su.getOutputStream());
    outputStream.writeBytes("pm disable com.bt.bms");

    outputStream.writeBytes("exit\n");
    outputStream.flush();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Is there any way I can see the result of the executed code?

Comment: Are you sure your application is running as root? An application that is not root, cannot 'su'.

Comment: the xposed framework has root permissions.
How do i check if the module itself is running as root.
Can you point me in the right direction.

Comment: Sure the framework has root permissions, but YOUR app does not.

Comment: This worked for me:
    try {
                 Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", "pm disable com.bt.bms" });
                 proc.waitFor();
             } catch (Exception ex) {
              XposedBridge.log("Could not reboot");
             }

Comment: "worked" is not very descriptive, I dont know how you are validating this... Are you saying you ran the command and confirmed that the package was disabled after you ran that command? If you re-enable it and run the command with JUST your app does it disable? I'm also confused because what you're saying contradicts what you are saying you we're seeing.

Comment: i included the mentioned code in my App and it worked. The app with that package name was disabled.Sorry for not being very clear.

Comment: So if it works now.. why is this still a question if the issue is resolved? You maybe should close it because it sounds/feels like a user error problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87432/discussion-between-himanshu-jain-and-joxtraex).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
               try {
                 Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", "pm disable com.bt.bms" });
                 proc.waitFor();
             } catch (Exception ex) {
                 XposedBridge.log("Could not reboot");
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `\n` at the end of your first command.

Try with this:

```
try {
    Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(su.getOutputStream());

    outputStream.writeBytes("pm disable com.bt.bms\n");
    outputStream.flush();

    outputStream.writeBytes("exit\n");
    outputStream.flush();
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```